# Draw SpatialPolygons with multiple subpolygons and holes using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, geospatial, broom

I would like to draw `SpatialPolygons` from library `sp` with holes in ggplot2.
Thanks to others questions on stackoverflow, I know that this is allowed while dealing with clockwise written polygons:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047643/geom-polygon-with-multiple-hole/12051278#12051278
Indeed, when transforming a `SpatialPolygons` using `broom::tidy` (replacing `ggplot2::fortify`), holes polygons are saved in clockwise direction to be drawn as holes.
In ggplot2, the way polygons with holes are drawn force to draw them once using `fill`, and another time using `colour`, otherwise you may see lines crossing polygons.
When dealing with multiple subpolygons, some with holes, this is more tricky, the order of points features as defined by `broom::tidy` may not allow for filling polygons (see image below).
Do any of you have a solution to get rid of this filling problem behaviour ?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)

# Create two polygons: second would be a hole inside the first
xy = cbind(
  x = c(13.4, 13.4, 13.6, 13.6, 13.4),
  y = c(48.9, 49, 49, 48.9, 48.9)
    )
hole.xy <- cbind(
  x = c(13.5, 13.5, 13.45, 13.45, 13.5),
  y = c(48.98, 48.92, 48.92, 48.98, 48.98)
  )

# Transform as SpatialPolygons with holes
xy.sp <- SpatialPolygons(list(
  Polygons(list(Polygon(xy),
                Polygon(hole.xy, hole = TRUE)), "1"),
  Polygons(list(Polygon(xy + 0.2),
                Polygon(xy + 0.35),
                Polygon(hole.xy + 0.2, hole = TRUE)), "2")
  ))

# Transform SpatialObject to be used by ggplot2
xy.sp.l <- broom::tidy(xy.sp)

ggplot(xy.sp.l) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id, fill = id))
```

[image: ggplot fill problem with SpatialPolygons with holes]
<sub>(source: [statnmap.com](https://statnmap.com/wp-content/uploads/ggplot_polygon_fill_problem.jpg))</sub>

Comment: One solution would involve separating the polygons in the SpatialPolygons  function call. e.g. Two polygons with id = 2 become 2a & 2b. Is this a possibility or are you looking for a solution from xy.sp.l onwards.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Could be a good time to "go over" to the `sf` package. Working with `sf` object is in fact much easier in `ggplot`, thanks to the `geom_sf` geometry:

```
library("sf")
library("rgeos")
sf_poly <- as(xy.sp, "sf")
sf::st_crs(sf_poly) <- 4326
sf_poly$id <- c(1,2)
ggplot(sf_poly) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = as.factor(id)))
```

[image]

Comment: Yes indeed. Your answer solves the problem asked here in a simple way. I guess this will encourage people having this problem to migrate to sf... I was personally waiting the moment when `sf` was stable enough with parameters and function names. However, this raises my other problem of being able to draw hatched area polygons with sf features. I will have to modify my function to allow this with sf and then leaflet with sf. But this is another question, for another time... Thanks.

Comment: I accept this answer to make people move to `sf`. But the second answer is awarded because this is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

Adding lines shows the source of the problem. The blue "polygon" is being drawn, lower -> upper -> hole.

[image]

This code (which is not very elegant, sorry) makes the path go back to the starting point of the first piece before proceeding to 3rd.

```
 library(dplyr)
    extra <- xy.sp.l %>%
        filter(piece != 1) %>%
        group_by(id, group) %>%
        summarise(last_pt = max(order))


for (n in 1:nrow(extra)) {
    id_ex <- as.character(extra[n,"id"])
    x <- subset(xy.sp.l, id == id_ex & piece == 1 & order == 1)
    x$order <- as.numeric(extra[n,"last_pt"]) + 0.5
    xy.sp.l <- rbind(xy.sp.l,x)
}

xy.sp.l <- xy.sp.l[order(xy.sp.l$id, xy.sp.l$order),]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Going back to one point of the first polygon seems to solve the problem for any new sub-polygon or polygon order. I guess this trick can be used for any polygons of library `sp` to be plotted in `ggplot2`.

Comment: I believe it would, as it avoids the problem of extra polygons (like the triangle above) being created.

Comment: I award this answer because it answers directly my question. However, to encourage people to move to `sf`, I accept the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

This post is a good question and already received great answers. I also believe people should learn how to work with `sf` objects as it is the next generation of the spatial data type in R. But I want to share that in this case `geom_spatial` from the `ggspatial` package could be an option to plot the SpatialPolygons.

```
library(sp)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggspatial)

ggplot() +
  geom_spatial(xy.sp, aes(fill = id))
# Ignoring argument 'mapping' in geom_spatial.SpatialPolygons
# Autodetect projection: assuming lat/lon (epsg 4326)
```

[image]